# Vue 3 Script Setup Typescript | Template ref: Parameter 'el' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Can anyone tell me why typescript is yelling at me with the following error?
`error TS7006: Parameter 'el' implicitly has an 'any' type. ref="(el) => saveRef(index, el)"`. I'm pretty sure correct type is set in `saveRef` function.

```
  <script lang="ts" setup>
    import FormComponent from '@/components/FormComponent.vue'

    const formRefs = ref<
      ComponentPublicInstance<typeof FormComponent>[]
    >([])

    function saveRef(
      index: number,
      el: ComponentPublicInstance<typeof FormComponent>
    ) {
      formRefs.value[index] = el
    }

    onBeforeUpdate(() => {
      formRefs.value = []
    })
  </script>

  <template>
    <div v-for="(component, index) in components" :key="index">
      <form-component
        :ref="(el) => saveRef(index, el)"
        :component="component"
        :index="index"
      />
   </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: The error is caused by a *parameter*, i.e. `(el) =>` part

Comment: Can  you tell my how can I fix it? Beacasuse as far as I know I can't use types in template `(el: ComponentPublicInstance<typeof FormComponent>) =>`

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not a good practice to keep redundant JS in a template. A proper solution is to define typed ref handler function in component script. Since it's supposed to be parametrized, it can be higher-order function:

```
function saveRef(
  index: number,
) {
  return (el: ComponentPublicInstance<typeof FormComponent>) => {
    formRefs.value[index] = el
  }
}
```

And use it as `:ref="saveRef(index)"`.